# Do the SilverHawks breathe?

Tags: silverhawks

in the 1980s Rankin-Bass cartoon **Silverhawks,** the titular team is a unit of cyborg space cops who have been modified ("partly metal, partly real") to live in deepest space. Modifications include mostly metal bodies, shoulder mounted lasers, and wings. I say "mostly" metal because almost every Hawk has parts of their arm and face exposed.

Usually, when in space, the Hawks will pull down a type of "flight mask" built into their bodies. However, this isn't *always* the case. Further more, as stated, there are portions of their human forms which are **directly exposed** to the cold of deep space, and yet they seem to have no problems with temperature. In the opening itself, we can see the Copper Kid *open faced* as he's fighting in space.

So, are the masks **specifically breathing apparatus** for the Hawks, or used more as defensive plating?

Furthermore... what is it that *powers* the Hawks, as in their mechanical aspects? I can't remember that ever being discussed...

Comment: Should the second question be asked separately?

Comment: @Jenayah I thought about it, honestly. But considering the question was dealing with their physical and mechanical structures, I thought they were linked enough to be answered within the same question.

Comment: It seems likely that everyone breathes in space in Silverhawks, and that the show's Science Advisor was only consulted to make up the quizzes at the end of most of the episodes.

Comment: @notovny Honestly, the _aliens_ being physically equipped to exist in the vacuum of space never bothered me. I just assumed their physical structures were different. The Silver Hawks themselves though always made me...uneasy. I could let go of the copper Kid, as he himself is an alien, but for a show that was so grounded in sci-fi, that just sort of struck me as odd. Then again, somehow the silver Hawks also manage to _fall downward_ [SOMEHOW] in space, so, you may be right and I might be asking too much of the toon...